# Kafka Streams API GroupBy behaviour

Tags: json, group-by, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ktable

I am new in kafka streams and I am trying to aggregate some streaming data into a KTable using groupBy function. The problem is the following:

The produced message is a json msg with the following format:

```
{ "current_ts": "2019-12-24 13:16:40.316952",
  "primary_keys": ["ID"],
  "before": null,
  "tokens": {"txid":"3.17.2493", 
             "csn":"64913009"},
  "op_type":"I",
  "after":  { "CODE":"AAAA41",
              "STATUS":"COMPLETED",
              "ID":24},
  "op_ts":"2019-12-24 13:16:40.316941",
  "table":"S_ORDER"}
```

I want to isolate the json field **"after"** and then create a KTable with **"key" = "ID"** and **value** the whole json **"after"**.

Firstly, I created a KStream to isolate the **"after"** json, and it works fine.

KStream code block: (Don't pay attention to the **if statement** because "before" and "after" have the same format.)

```
KStream<String, String> s_order_list = s_order
                .mapValues(value -> {
                    String time;
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(value);
                    if (json.getString("op_type").equals("I")) {
                        time = "after";
                    }else {
                        time = "before";
                    }
                    JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(json.getJSONObject(time).toString());
                    return json2.toString();
                });
```

The output, as expected, is the following:

```
...
null {"CODE":"AAAA48","STATUS":"SUBMITTED","ID":6}
null {"CODE":"AAAA16","STATUS":"COMPLETED","ID":1}
null {"CODE":"AAAA3","STATUS":"SUBMITTED","ID":25}
null {"CODE":"AAAA29","STATUS":"SUBMITTED","ID":23}
...
```

Afterwards, I implement a KTable to groupBy the "ID" of the json.

KTable code block:

```
  KTable<String, String> s_table = s_order_list
                .groupBy((key, value) -> {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(value);
                    return json.getString("ID");
                });
```

And there is an error that I want to create `KTable<String, String>` but I am creating `GroupedStream<Object,String>`.

```
Required type: KTable<String,String>
Provided:KGroupedStream<Object,String>
no instance(s) of type variable(s) KR exist so that KGroupedStream<KR, String> conforms to KTable<String, String>
```

In conclusion, the question is what exactly are KGroupedStreams and how to implement a KTable properly ?

Comment: Why can't you just start with putting the ID as the key in the producer? (are you using Debezium?)

Comment: How do you create your upstream objects, ie, `s_order` -- seems it's just a generic issue.

Comment: A KStream cannot be converted to a KTable. So why not co-partition the data using the KTable itself.

Comment: @cricket_007 No I am not using Debezium. In the project that I am working on, I can't change the messages that are being published by the producer.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax s_order is another stream that is built with ``builder.stream("topic-name")``. It is redundant actually, it could be just s_order_list "reading messages" from the topic directly.

Comment: Did you specify the types of the original stream? Maybe you need to so `builder.<keyType, ValueType>("topic-name");` to tell the compiler to correct types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `groupBy` processor, you can use a stateful processor, [like `aggregate` or `reduce` (that processors returns `KTable`)](https://kafka.apache.org/33/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#id11). You can do something like this:

```
KGroupedStream<String, String> s_table = s_order_list
                     .groupBy((key, value) ->
                         new JSONObject(value).getString("ID"),
                         Grouped.with(
                                 Serdes.String(),
                                 Serdes.String())
                     );

KTable<String, StringAggregate> aggregateStrings = s_table.aggregate(
                     (StringAggregate::new),
                     (key, value, aggregate) -> aggregate.addElement(value));
```

StringAggregate looks like:

```
public class StringAggregate {

    private List<String> elements = new ArrayList<>();

    public StringAggregate addElement(String element){
        elements.add(element);
        return this;
    }
    //other methods
}
```