# Kafka Streams API GroupBy behaviour

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

So I've been trying to aggregate some stream data to a KTable using Kafka stream. My JSON from the topic looks like

```
{
   "id": "d04a6184-e805-4ceb-9aaf-b2ab0139ee84",
   "person": {
      "id": "d04a6184-e805-4ceb-9aaf-b2ab0139ee84",
      "createdBy": "user",
      "createdDate": "2023-01-01T00:28:58.161Z",
      "name": "person 1",
      "description": "test1"
   }
}....
```

```
KStream<Object, String> firstStream = builder.stream("topic-1").mapValues(value -> {
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(value));
  JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(json.getJSONObject("person").toString());
  return json2.toString();
});
```

I get something like

```
null{"createdDate":"2023-01-01T00:28:58.161Z","createdBy":"user","name":"person 1","description":"test1","id":"d04a6184-e805-4ceb-9aaf-b2ab0139ee84"}
null{"createdDate":"2023-01-01T00:29:07.862Z","createdBy":"user","name":"person 2","description":"test 2","id":"48d8b895-eb27-4977-9dbc-adb8fbf649d8"}
null{"createdDate":"2023-01-01T00:29:12.261Z","createdBy":"anonymousUser","name":"person 2","description":"test 2 updated","id":"d8b895-eb27-4977-9dbc-adb8fbf649d8"}
```

I want to group this data in such a way such that
person 1 will hold one JSON associated with it
person 2 will hold a List of both JSON associated with it

I have checked this [Kafka Streams API GroupBy behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59542326/kafka-streams-api-groupby-behaviour) which describes the same problem but the solution given there doesn't work for me. Do I have to perform any extra operations? Please help

Comment: Can you show the groupby call you tried and what doesn't work as intended?

Comment: the same that has been defined here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59542326/kafka-streams-api-groupby-behaviour

Answer (score 1):

In order to `groupBy`, you need a pairing key. So, use `map` to extract the `name` of each person.

Then, as the linked answer says, you need to `aggregate` after grouping to "combine data per person", across events.

By the way, you should setup the Streams config with JsonSerde for values rather than String Serde in order to reduce the need to manually parse each event.

Comment: sounds insightful. is there some kind of reference, especially to config with JsonSerde. only have knowledge that serde are related to serialization and deserialization

Comment: Import JSON serializer+deserializer classes from `org.apache.kafka.connect.json` package ( from `org.apache.kafka:connect-json` dependency), then create `Serde<JsonNode> jsonSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(jsonSerializer, jsonDeserializer);`